# Can I change the permissions for a test user?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I was wondering if there is a way to change the permissions of a test user. It's not for a real user. Facebook docs on [test user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) does not show that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but you can access your facebook application as a test user and it will request for the additional permissions.

I'd like to know how to use the console or REST API to do it though.

Answer (score 8):

In order to change permission directly via the API you can call the method that adds existing test-users to other Apps.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

> Adding existing test users to other apps
>
> You can add existing test users to other apps by using the Graph API with the app access    token that you're adding the user to.
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
>     installed=true
>     &permissions=read_stream
>     &uid=TEST_USER_ID
>     &owner_access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN_OWNER
>     &access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
>     &method=post

Since the new App is the same as to old App, simply use the same App Access Token, so APP_ACCESS_TOKEN_OWNER = APP_ACCESS_TOKEN.

Then you can change the permission list ( '&permissions=read_stream' )  as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recreate test users and if they are extended permissions I found that you should not authorise the app. This isn't working.

Then switch to the test user using the https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/permissions  tool.

If you hit your app for the first time now you should be presented with the extended permission dialogue. After that the test user should have the correct permissions.

If you have more than one app, you can copy the user to another app so you don't have to delete the account if that is desired. re adding them to the app your working on will prompt the permissions dialogue.

Comment: this wont work as test users cannot access the developers. domain

Comment: Pretty sure that it worked at the time that I answered this as I was working with it that way at the time. If this has changed since and perhaps there is some documentation, I should remove the answer